# How can I get a UNIX time of a specified label in Pine Script v5?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Iam trying to get a UNIX time when the label got placed , i use pivot high and low to draw a label , but i need to get UNIX Time when the label is placed. have read manual of pinescript v5 , got error time always return 1969-12-31 19.00 when i use  "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", syminfo.timezone as a format time from unix time. script is attach below.

```
//@version=5
indicator("LittleQ", shorttitle="LQ", overlay=true, max_labels_count=500,max_bars_back = 5000)

lengthGroupTitle = "LENGTH LEFT / RIGHT"
colorGroupTitle = "Text Color / Label Color"
leftLenH = input.int(title="Pivot High", defval=10, minval=1, inline="Pivot High", group=lengthGroupTitle)
rightLenH = input.int(title="/", defval=10, minval=1, inline="Pivot High", group=lengthGroupTitle)
textColorH = input(title="Pivot High", defval=color.white, inline="Pivot High", group=colorGroupTitle)
labelColorH = input(title="", defval=color.blue, inline="Pivot High", group=colorGroupTitle)

leftLenL = input.int(title="Pivot Low", defval=10, minval=1, inline="Pivot Low", group=lengthGroupTitle)
rightLenL = input.int(title="/", defval=10, minval=1, inline="Pivot Low", group=lengthGroupTitle)
textColorL = input(title="Pivot Low", defval=color.white, inline="Pivot Low", group=colorGroupTitle)
labelColorL = input(title="", defval=color.red, inline="Pivot Low", group=colorGroupTitle)


//Trend Filter
ema1 = ta.ema(close,200)


Ctrend = if ema1[5] > ema1[4] and ema1[4]>ema1[3] and ema1[3]>ema1[2] and ema1[2]>ema1[1] and ema1[1]>1[0]
    "Bearish",
else
    ema1[5]<ema1[4] and ema1[4]<ema1[3] and ema1[3]<ema1[2] and ema1[2]<ema1[1] and ema1[1]<ema1[0]
    "Bullish",

// table input
showTable     = input.bool(true, "Show Table")
tablePosInput = input.string(title="Position", defval="Top Right", options=["Bottom Left", "Bottom Right", "Top Left", "Top Right"], tooltip="Select where you want the table to draw.")
var tablePos  = tablePosInput == "Bottom Left" ? position.bottom_left : tablePosInput == "Bottom Right" ? position.bottom_right : tablePosInput == "Top Left" ? position.top_left : tablePosInput == "Top Right" ? position.top_right : na


ph = ta.pivothigh(leftLenH, rightLenH)
pl = ta.pivotlow(leftLenL, rightLenL)
var float ph_valid = 0
var float ph0 = 0
var float ph1 = 0
var float ph2 = 0
var float pl0 = 0
var float pl1 = 0
var float pl2 = 0


ph_non_na = nz(ph,0) // stores 0's instead of na's for non-pivot-pointed bars

// Assigns non-na values to pre-instantiated variables
if ph_non_na != 0
    ph2 := ph1
    ph1 := ph0
    ph0 := ph_non_na
else
    ph2 := ph2
    ph1 := ph1
    ph0 := ph0

pl_non_na = nz(pl,0) // stores 0's instead of na's for non-pivot-pointed bars

// Assigns non-na values to pre-instantiated variables
if pl_non_na != 0
    pl2 := pl1
    pl1 := pl0
    pl0 := pl_non_na
else
    pl2 := pl2
    pl1 := pl1
    pl0 := pl0



drawLabel(_offset, _pivot, _style, _color, _textColor) =>
    if not na(_pivot)
        label.new(bar_index[_offset], _pivot, str.tostring(_pivot, format.mintick), style=_style, color=_color, textcolor=_textColor)
        

lph0 = drawLabel(rightLenH, ph, label.style_label_down, labelColorH, textColorH)
drawLabel(rightLenL, pl, label.style_label_up, labelColorL, textColorL)

tph0 = label.get_x(lph0)

// table color
strongRed   = color.rgb(255, 25, 25, 25)
strongGreen = color.rgb(19, 200, 25, 25)
blue        = color.rgb(20, 123, 134, 25)

var dataTable = table.new(tablePos, columns = 4, rows = 5, border_color = color.rgb(40, 40, 40, 25), border_width = 2)
if showTable
    table.cell(dataTable, 1, 1, text = str.tostring(Ctrend),bgcolor =str.contains(Ctrend,"Bull")? strongGreen : strongRed,text_color = color.white)
    table.cell(dataTable, 1, 2, text = "Last1", bgcolor = blue, text_color = color.white)
    table.cell(dataTable, 1, 3, text = "Last2", bgcolor = blue, text_color = color.white)
    table.cell(dataTable, 1, 4, text = "Last3 ", bgcolor = blue, text_color = color.white)
    table.cell(dataTable, 2, 1, text = "Value  ", bgcolor = blue, text_color = color.white)
    table.cell(dataTable, 3, 1, text = "Date Time", bgcolor = blue, text_color = color.white)
    table.cell(dataTable, 2, 2, text = str.tostring(ph0), bgcolor = blue, text_color = color.white)
    table.cell(dataTable, 2, 3, text = str.tostring(ph1), bgcolor = blue, text_color = color.white)
    table.cell(dataTable, 2, 4, text = str.tostring(ph2), bgcolor = blue, text_color = color.white)
    table.cell(dataTable, 3, 2, text = str.format_time(tph0,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm",syminfo.timezone), bgcolor = blue, text_color = color.white)
```

Comment: and tryed your suggest but is show error 2 error, 1.Shadowing variable 'UnixTime' which exists in parent scope. Did you want to use the ':=' operator instead of '=' ? , 2. Undeclared identifier '_pivot' . i think its caused we can got a specified label_id for the last 3 label. maybe caused by a loop . iam thinking to draw label just last of 3 pivot_high and pivot_low maybe can work.

Comment: Warm welcome to SO. Please try to use correct upper case letters, e.g. in the beginning of your title, sentences or the word "I". This would be gentle to your readers. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Then update your question with code to show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this to get the Unix time when your label is drawn :
Add this at the end of your code to get the UnixTime of the last drawn label :

```
var UnixTime = 0
if not na (_pivot)
    // UNIX time is the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 UTC, 1 January 1970.
    UnixTime := time
```

Comment: hello sir , thanks for your help . have edited to post entire script.  
and tryed your suggest but is show error 2 error, 1.Shadowing variable 'UnixTime' which exists in parent scope. Did you want to use the ':=' operator instead of '=' ? , 2. Undeclared identifier '_pivot' . i think its caused we can got a specified label_id for the last 3 label. maybe caused by a loop . iam thinking to draw label just last of 3 pivot_high and pivot_low maybe can work.

Comment: sadly not working sir.